# Internal link between tabs to specific section in R Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I want to link to a specific content of another `tabPanel` within an R Shiny app. I've found plenty of advice on how to do the half part of it respectively: there are solutions how to use an `anchor` tag to link to content *within* a `tabPanel`...

- [SO: Create link to the other part of the Shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605185/create-link-to-the-other-part-of-the-shiny-app/28605517#28605517)

... and on hwo to direct the link to *another* `tabPanel`:

- [SO: [Shiny]: Add link to another tabPanel in another tabPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36412407/shiny-add-link-to-another-tabpanel-in-another-tabpanel)
- [SO: Linking to a tab or panel of a shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34315485/linking-to-a-tab-or-panel-of-a-shiny-app)
- [SO: Externally link to specific tabPanel in Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33021757/externally-link-to-specific-tabpanel-in-shiny-app)
- [Creating Internal Links - Defining Application Navigation by David Ruvolo](https://davidruvolo51.github.io/shinytutorials/tutorials/shiny-link/)

However, I need a combination of both: a link switching the view to another `tabPanel` at a specific location. In this app, [based on mihasa's example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36412407/4112892), there are two `tabPanels`, where the first (`Home`) holds some text upon clicking that, the app should redirect to a section with the id `visitme` in `Tab2`.

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(
  navbarPage("Header",
             tabPanel("Home",
                      fluidPage(
                        "bring me to the desired point in Tab2")),
             tabPanel("Tab2",
                      "Some Text inside Tab 2.",
                      div("This is a long div to visualize the redirection",
                        style = "background-color: gray;
                                height: 1000px;
                                width: 100px;"),
                      div(id = "visitme",
                          "This is the part where the redirection shall land."),
                      div("Another long div",
                          style = "background-color: gray;
                                  height: 500px;
                                  width: 100px;"))))

server = function(input, output, session){}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [K. Rohde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36426258/4112892) as starting point, their JavaScript was extended by a second argument for the given id and a command, that scrolls to it (`document.getElementById(anchorName).scrollIntoView()`), allows to move to a certain section within a given `tabPanel` after switching to it.

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(
  navbarPage("Header",
             tabPanel("Home",
                      tags$head(tags$script(HTML('
                        var fakeClick = function(tabName, anchorName) {
                          var dropdownList = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
                          for (var i = 0; i < dropdownList.length; i++) {
                            var link = dropdownList[i];
                            if(link.getAttribute("data-value") == tabName) {
                              link.click();
                              document.getElementById(anchorName).scrollIntoView({
                                behavior: "smooth"
                                });
                            };
                          }
                        };
                                                 '))),
                      fluidPage(
                        span("bring me to end of tab2",
                             onclick = "fakeClick('Tab2', 'visitme')"))),
             tabPanel("Tab2",
                      "Some Text inside Tab 2.",
                      div("This is a long div to visualize the redirection",
                        style = "background-color: gray;
                                height: 1000px;
                                width: 100px;"),
                      div(id = "visitme",
                          "This is the part where the redirection shall land."),
                      div("Another long div",
                          style = "background-color: gray;
                                  height: 1000px;
                                  width: 100px;"))))

server = function(input, output, session){}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```